# JAVA-I don't want clicking on my app make other apps lose focus

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

Wow, what a stupid question you might say. But is it possible? I have a mouse move event in a Jpanel and it works even when the application is not in focus, now can I have something like that for the clicking event or something similar. And most importantly I don't want other apps (even something like the main menu) to lose focus when i click on my app.
I thought of the system's event queue but i'm not sure where that would lead me to.

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT - the purpose]**
I want to create an app that mimics the users interactions with the system in a later time. for example a user takes the mouse and clicks and writes and my app will mimic that in say 2 hours time. ofcourse i would need a system hook for the outer events but i wanted to avoid os-dependant code so i basically capture the screen, take it to my app,for example the user clicks on an icon in the captured picture and then for making that come to life, i translate the coordinates to the real icon and click it (with a Robot) and in this way i can capture the user's events in my own app. the problem occurs when the user clicks on the main menu or right clicks (he's doing that in my app, and my app does that to the system so my app is in between) and ofcourse the real main menu will lose focus when the user tries to click on one of it's items.

sorry for my english.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could tell us why you would want to do do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I follow what you are trying to do. But the concept of an app getting focus when you click on it is fundamental to the GUI and I suspect rather difficult to get around.

I just found this:

Focusable Windows

To support palette windows and input methods, client code can prevent a Window from becoming the focused Window. By transitivity, this prevents the Window or any of its descendants from becoming the focus owner. Non-focusable Windows may still own Windows that are focusable. By default, every Frame and Dialog is focusable. Every Window which is not a Frame or Dialog, but whose nearest owning Frame or Dialog is showing on the screen, and which has at least one Component in its focus traversal cycle, is also focusable by default. To make a Window non-focusable, use Window.setFocusableWindowState(false).

In this doucment http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html

That sounds like it might do what you want.

Comment: Wow, Thanks again, it worked. I got the root window and set it as not focusable. :)